# internal speakers + microphones not working after system update (ubuntu 14.04, Dell Latitude, HDA Intel PCH)

Tags: 14.04, dell, microphone, speakers, hda-intel

Recently, after updating my system (ubuntu 14.04), both the internal speakers and the microphones have stopped working...

I have used alsadriver and the sound settings to verify nothing was muted.

Weirdly, the volume control tells me that speakers are unavailable, and I have no 'speakers' entry in alsadriver. Also, in the 'input devices' menu of Volume Control, the only available microphones are called 'plugged in' - while I do not I have any 'plugged in' microphones. The internal microphone is said 'unavailable'.

I have been trying to do a clean re-installation of the sound-managing packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio unity-control-center
```

But it did not help... The positive side being that headphones still work...

Any idea how to fix this? My laptop is a dell latitude, and my sound card is HDA Intel PCH.

Thanks very much for any help.

Laureline

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess was that the problem is with the driver, and not with pulse audio or alsa. After some googling I am not so sure, as there are quite a few references to alsa having problems with HDA intel cards.
for exmaple:

http://www.stchman.com/alsa_update.html

Or

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

so you might want to make sure that Ubuntu recognized the sound card by seeing if it shows when you type:

```
sudo lshw -short
```

If it shows, I highly recommend following this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: When using 'sudo lshw -short', the sound card does not seem to appear (at least, not explicitly: the only mutlimedia entries are "GF119 HDMI Audio Controller" and "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family"). The funny thing is that the card appears in the terminal-triggered alsamixer. Would you recommend following   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend it, But if you found it through the alsamixer I'd try the link I suggested above first. Good luck! :)